# How can I fix the problem with this strange error that show me Node v21.2.0 when I want to run "npm run build" or "npm start"?

Tags: node.js, error-handling

I have strange problem, that I can't handle it. I have that error when I try to start my site by command "npm start" (application made with create-react-app).

Starting the development server...

Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported
at new Hash (node:internal/crypto/hash:68:19)
at Object.createHash (node:crypto:138:10)
at module.exports (C:\Users\Patryk\uicookies\node_modules\webpack\lib\util\createHash.js:135:53)
at NormalModule._initBuildHash (C:\Users\Patryk\uicookies\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:417:16)
at handleParseError (C:\Users\Patryk\uicookies\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:471:10)
at C:\Users\Patryk\uicookies\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:503:5
at C:\Users\Patryk\uicookies\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:358:12
at C:\Users\Patryk\uicookies\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:373:3
at iterateNormalLoaders (C:\Users\Patryk\uicookies\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:214:10)
at iterateNormalLoaders (C:\Users\Patryk\uicookies\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:221:10)
C:\Users\Patryk\uicookies\node_modules\react-scripts\scripts\start.js:19
throw err;
^

Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported
at new Hash (node:internal/crypto/hash:68:19)
at Object.createHash (node:crypto:138:10)
at module.exports (C:\Users\Patryk\uicookies\node_modules\webpack\lib\util\createHash.js:135:53)
at NormalModule._initBuildHash (C:\Users\Patryk\uicookies\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:417:16)
at C:\Users\Patryk\uicookies\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:452:10
at C:\Users\Patryk\uicookies\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:323:13
at C:\Users\Patryk\uicookies\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:367:11
at C:\Users\Patryk\uicookies\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:233:18
at context.callback (C:\Users\Patryk\uicookies\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:111:13)
at C:\Users\Patryk\uicookies\node_modules\babel-loader\lib\index.js:59:103 {
opensslErrorStack: [ 'error:03000086:digital envelope routines::initialization error' ],
library: 'digital envelope routines',
reason: 'unsupported',
code: 'ERR_OSSL_EVP_UNSUPPORTED'
}

Node.js v21.2.0

Does anyone know how to make it work?

I tried to run my app by "npm start" and deploy on Vercel, but I couldn't do it. So I intalled "npm install node@latest" and that gave me this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are a few things you can try to fix the problem:

1. **Downgrade Node.js:** If the latest Node.js version is causing trouble, switch to a stable one like the LTS (Long Term Support) version using Node Version Manager (nvm).

   ```bash
   nvm install --lts
   nvm use --lts
   ```
2. **Update npm:** Ensure you're rocking the newest npm version.

   ```bash
   npm install -g npm@latest
   ```
3. **Clear npm cache:** Wipe out any gunk in the npm cache that might be causing issues.

   ```bash
   npm cache clean -f
   ```
4. **Reinstall Node Modules:** Trash the `node_modules` folder and reinstall your dependencies.

   ```bash
   rm -rf node_modules
   npm install
   ```
5. **Check webpack version:** Confirm you've got a webpack version that plays nice with your Node.js. Sometimes, certain webpack versions clash with specific Node.js versions.

   ```bash
   npm install webpack@latest
   ```

Give it another whirl after following these steps and firing up `npm start` again. If the gremlins are still there, dig into your project's dependencies—they might be the culprits.

Comment: The last one advice helped me with solving my problem. Thank You very much!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.

```
When i run`npm install webpack@latestun` 

npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: @angular-devkit/build-angular@12.2.17
npm ERR! Found: karma@3.1.4
npm ERR! node_modules/karma
npm ERR!   peer karma@"*" from karma-jasmine@1.1.2
npm ERR!   node_modules/karma-jasmine
npm ERR!     karma-jasmine@"^1.0.2" from karma-jasmine-html-reporter@0.2.2
npm ERR!     node_modules/karma-jasmine-html-reporter
npm ERR!       dev karma-jasmine-html-reporter@"^0.2.2" from the root project
npm ERR!     dev karma-jasmine@"~1.1.2" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer karma@">=0.9" from karma-jasmine-html-reporter@0.2.2
npm ERR!   node_modules/karma-jasmine-html-reporter
npm ERR!     dev karma-jasmine-html-reporter@"^0.2.2" from the root project
npm ERR!   1 more (the root project)
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peerOptional karma@"^6.3.0" from @angular-devkit/build-angular@12.2.17
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular
npm ERR!   dev @angular-devkit/build-angular@"^12.2.17" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: karma@6.4.2
npm ERR! node_modules/karma
npm ERR!   peerOptional karma@"^6.3.0" from @angular-devkit/build-angular@12.2.17
npm ERR!   node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular
npm ERR!     dev @angular-devkit/build-angular@"^12.2.17" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR!
npm ERR! For a full report see:
npm ERR! C:\Users\djosh\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2024-01-19T12_29_34_829Z-eresolve-report.txt
```

Do i need to update angular or this karma?